# EFCore Monitor Interceptor with logging queries

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I created a SqlMonitorInterceptor that will check the execution time of queries and log errors. The main idea is to log queries in such a way that they can be easily copied into SQL Server Management Studio and executed.

SqlMonitorInterceptor:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WebApplication.Data
{
    public class SqlMonitorInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
    {
        private readonly ILogger<SqlMonitorInterceptor> logger;

        public SqlMonitorInterceptor(ILogger<SqlMonitorInterceptor> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public override void CommandFailed(DbCommand command, CommandErrorEventData eventData)
        {
            if (eventData.Exception is not null)
            {
                logger.LogError(eventData.Exception, "Command:\r\n{Command}\r\nfailed with Exception.", GetGeneratedQuery(command));
            }
        }

        public override Task CommandFailedAsync(DbCommand command, CommandErrorEventData eventData, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            CommandFailed(command, eventData);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public override int NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, CommandExecutedEventData eventData, int result)
        {
            CommandExecuted(eventData);

            return result;
        }

        public override ValueTask<int> NonQueryExecutedAsync(DbCommand command, CommandExecutedEventData eventData, int result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            CommandExecuted(eventData);

            return new ValueTask<int>(result);
        }

        public override DbDataReader ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, CommandExecutedEventData eventData, DbDataReader result)
        {
            CommandExecuted(eventData);

            return result;
        }

        public override ValueTask<DbDataReader> ReaderExecutedAsync(DbCommand command, CommandExecutedEventData eventData, DbDataReader result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            CommandExecuted(eventData);

            return new ValueTask<DbDataReader>(result);
        }

        public override object ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, CommandExecutedEventData eventData, object result)
        {
            CommandExecuted(eventData);

            return result;
        }

        public override ValueTask<object> ScalarExecutedAsync(DbCommand command, CommandExecutedEventData eventData, object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            CommandExecuted(eventData);

            return new ValueTask<object>(result);
        }

        private void CommandExecuted(CommandExecutedEventData eventData)
        {
            // Log command if non-async.
            if (!eventData.IsAsync)
            {
                logger.LogWarning("Non-async command used:\r\n{Command}", GetGeneratedQuery(eventData.Command));
            }

            // Log command if too slow.
            if (eventData.Duration > AppConfiguration.SqlPerformance_WarningThreshold)
            {
                logger.LogDebug("Query time ({Duration}ms) exceeded the threshold of {Threshold}ms. Command:\r\n{Command}",
                    eventData.Duration.TotalMilliseconds,
                    AppConfiguration.SqlPerformance_WarningThreshold.TotalMilliseconds,
                    GetGeneratedQuery(eventData.Command));
            }
        }

        private static string GetGeneratedQuery(DbCommand command)
        {
            var quotedParameterTypes = new DbType[] {
                DbType.Date, DbType.DateTime, DbType.DateTime2, DbType.DateTimeOffset,
                DbType.Guid, DbType.AnsiString, DbType.String,
                DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength, DbType.StringFixedLength
            };

            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (DbParameter p in command.Parameters)
            {
                sb.Append($"DECLARE {p.ParameterName}");
                sb.Append(' ');
                if (p is SqlParameter sqlParameter)
                {
                    sb.Append(sqlParameter.SqlDbType.ToString().ToLower());
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(p.DbType.ToString().ToLower());
                }
                if (p.Size > 0)
                {
                    sb.Append("(" + (p.Size > 4000 ? "max" : p.Size.ToString()) + ")");
                }
                else if (p.Precision > 0)
                {
                    sb.Append("(" + p.Precision.ToString() + (p.Scale > 0 ? "," + p.Scale.ToString() : "") + ")");
                }

                sb.Append(' ');
                string pValStr = quotedParameterTypes.Contains(p.DbType) ? $"'{p.Value}'" : p.Value.ToString();
                sb.Append($"= {pValStr};");
                sb.AppendLine();
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
            sb.Append(command.CommandText);

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Example of generated log:

```
Query time (878.28ms) exceeded the threshold of 500ms. Command:

DECLARE @__8__locals1_entityDB_Id_0 int = 1094610;
DECLARE @__8__locals1_entityDB_CustomerId_1 uniqueidentifier = 'f47253a5-d660-4faf-408d-08d833e8e27b';
DECLARE @__phone_2 nvarchar(63) = '+79991111111';

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Leads] AS [l]
WHERE (([l].[Id] <> @__8__locals1_entityDB_Id_0) AND ([l].[CustomerId] = @__8__locals1_entityDB_CustomerId_1)) AND ((@__phone_2 LIKE N'') OR (CHARINDEX(@__phone_2, [l].[PhoneNumbers]) > 0))
```

Do you see any improvement / issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `CommandFailed`

- I would suggest to check whether the `eventData` `is not null` as well, not just its `Exception`
- Minor, but with the log severity (`LogError`) you have already indicated that the `command has failed with an exception`

  - So the log message might contain facts that are already part of the log itself

#### `CommandFailedAsync`

- Always returning with `Task.CompletedTask` might not be the best solution for all scenarios

  - For example if the `cancellationToken` has been already requested for cancellation then it might make sense to return with a canceled task as well to bubble up the cancellation fact

```
return cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested 
       ? Task.FromCanceled(cancellationToken) 
       : Task.CompletedTask
```

#### `CommandExecuted`

- It might make sense to have two separate versions of this method

  - One for the sync methods and another for the async ones
- It might make sense to use `>=` whenever you check `Duration` against threshold

  - With that you would log those methods as well which are reached the limit not just those which are exceeded

#### `GetGeneratedQuery`

- The `quotedParameterTypes` collection could be declared as a static class level member
- Naming a stringBuilder to `sb` might seem really handy but adding more meaningful name like `commandStringBuilder` would increase legibility
- Yet again naming an iteration variable to `p` might not be the best choice
- The first if-else block could be simplified with a conditional operator

```
sb.Append(dbParam is SqlParameter sqlParameter
    ? sqlParameter.SqlDbType.ToString().ToLower()
    : dbParam.DbType.ToString().ToLower());
```

- `p.Size > 4000`: It might make sense to introduce a class level constant for this magic number or make it configurable
- Inside the second if-else if block you could also use string interpolation instead of concatenation

  - With that you could avoid to write the `.ToString()` everywhere
- Based on its name I have no idea what is `pValStr`